# How can I associate an object with a Google Maps marker?

Tags: android, object, location, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am building an Android GPS application which shows the nearest places based on the users current location. I am using a MapFragment and I am placing markers down on the map like this inside an AsyncTask:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) { 
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        HashMap<String,String> location = new HashMap<String,String>();
        location = list.get(i);

        String type = location.get("type");
        int marker = getTypeDrawable(type);

        LatLng position = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(location.get("lat")), Float.parseFloat(location.get("long")));
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(position)
        .title(location.get("name"))
        .snippet(location.get("distance") + location.get("type"))                                  
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(marker)));
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finished retrieving nearby locations",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         
}
```

This is my global variable list which contains all the information of the nearest locatoins: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;`

My plan is to display a popup dialog when I click on the marker, just like the geocaching application 'C:Geo'. My problem is, I don't know how to show the information of that marker inside the dialog. As you can see, I am using the `map.addMarker()` method but there is no way where I can associate that location with that marker.

I wish to make a popup dialog like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
 //Get location associated with marker. 
//Fill popup dialog with information associated 
//with location and then invoke the dialog.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chose something that identifies the marker and the location uniquely. Maybe that's the title you set on the marker (you'll have some corresponding string in your locations) or the Lat/Lng combo. When the user taps a marker, you'll receive that marker in your [onMarkerClick(Marker marker)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) method , you read the title or lat/lng from the marker and look up the corresponding location from your locations. For example you could iterate through your HashMap of locations and check if that location has the same lat/lng as your marker, then you have the location that correspons with your marker.

There sure are more efficient ways, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but it seemed very efficient

Comment: It doesn't have to be, create a small POJO for your locations where you save your two Strings and in your class above make a HashMap<LatLng,YourLocationClass> then you can directly look up that location with the LatLng key.

Comment: Mmmm, what should the two strings be? I'll give it a shot

Comment: I don't know how exactly your locations look like, I suppose you have some name, some text, an Id, Lat and Lon or whatever. What I meant to say was to have a HashMap with 1. an identifying key and 2. your location object so you can easily look up the object when a marker is tapped.

Comment: Okok, so if do marker.getId() and then do hashmap.put(markerID, locationObject); ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the format of your desired method, I'd think you could use the hashcode of the marker as a key to access a location.  I haven't tried it myself, but my following idea should work (and be more efficient).
First, you'd have to change the way you add the marker, to:

```
Marker locationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(position)
    .title(location.get("name"))
    .snippet(location.get("distance") + location.get("type"))                                  
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(marker)));
```

This assures that you can access the added marker object. Then, have a `HashMap` with an `Integer` as a key, and a `Location` as the resulting object. Store the location with the key of the marker's hashcode, which you can access with: `marker.hashCode();`

I normally use the `getTag()`/`setTag()` methods to save object references, but unfortunately the Marker class doesn't have tags :(

A possible caveat to this way, is that MAYBE the hashCode will collide for 2 markers. I don't know how likely that would be, and that would be something to look into/test.